# Node tutorial - LearnYouNode - Juggling Async - using nested callbacks

Tags: node.js, asynchronous

I was trying to solve the "Juggling Async" problem in the "learnyounode" workshop from [nodeschool.io](http://nodeschool.io). I saw a lot of questions here about this problem where it is not working because the url's were being called from a loop. I understand why that wouldn't work. 
I had tried something like this.

```
var http=require('http');
console.log(process.argv[2],process.argv[3],process.argv[4]);
fn(process.argv[2],
    fn(process.argv[3],
        fn(process.argv[4])));


function fn(url,callback){
  http.get(url,function(response){
    var string='';
    response.setEncoding('utf8');
    response.on('data',function(data){
      string+=data;
    });
    response.on('end',function(){
      console.log(url,string);
      if (callback) {
        callback();
      }
    });
  });
};
```

As per my understanding, the second GET call should go out only after the first one has ended, since it is being initiated after response end. But the output is always in different order.

I have seen the correct solution. I know that doing it this way fails to leverage the advantage of async, but shouldn't the callbacks make it output in order?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you pass in a function as a callback, you need to only pass in the function name or function definition. By providing the arguments, you are actually calling the function.

E.g. let's say you had a function f1 that took in another function as a parameter, and another function f2 that you want to pass into f1:

```
function f1(func_param) {
    console.log('Executing f1!');
}
function f2(a_param) {
    console.log('Executing f2!');
}
```

When you do the following call (which is similar to what you are doing, providing a callback function and specifying parameters for the callback):

```
f1(f2(process.argv[2]));
```

You're evaluating f2 first, so 'Executing f2!' will print first. The return of f2 will get passed as a parameter into f1, which will execute and print 'Executing f1!'

In your call

```
fn(process.argv[2],
fn(process.argv[3],
    fn(process.argv[4])));
```

You are saying, let's pass the result of fn(process.argv[4]) as a callback to fn(process.argv[3]), and we'll get the result of calling that and pass that as a callback to fn(process.argv[2]).